# How is the weak-star topology useful?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Today I learnt something about the weak-star topology, but I don't know what the use of weak-star topology is. I hope someone can tell me what we can do with the weak-star topology. Thanks in advance!

Comment: We have a nice compactness result, for starters: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Alaoglu_theorem

Comment: Also, forget about what it's useful for at the moment, it's only natural to consider the topology of pointwise convergence for elements of the dual. On top of that, as Zack L mentioned, there are compactness results, such as Alaoglu and Krein-Milman.

Comment: thanks. I have one more question. In class, the teacher said that the dual space of $L_{p}$ is $L_{q}$ while $1/p+1/q=1$, while when p is infinte there is an exception. We know that the dual of a space is the set of all the bounded fuctionals on it. How can we say that the dual space of $L_{p}$ is $L_{q}$ ,since, in my opinion, $L_{q}$ is not a space containing the functionals of $L_{p}$.

Comment: @Martin: You're absolutely right. People will often say things are "equal" or "identical" when they mean "canonically isomorphic". Depending on how comfortable you are with this sloppiness, it can either a convenience or an annoyance.

Comment: It's not. Notice that if we take $L_p$ and a function $g \in L_q$, then we can define an operator on $L_p$ by $f \mapsto \int fg$. This is a bounded linear operator and so can be thought of as an element in the dual of $L_p$. As it turns out, every linear operator arises this way.

Comment: «In your opinion»?! Are the elements of $L_q$ or not linear functionals on $L_p$? You can certainly answer this :-)

Comment: @Zach L. yup! that is ensured by Riesz Representation Thm, am I right? I think Zev has answered my question. I am just wondering why the teacher was saying that thet are 'equal'. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Zev Chonoles Thank you so much!!

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Alvarez♦ I think they are not~

Comment: As Zach L. mentioned, the weak-$\ast$ topology gives rise to the Banach--Alaoglu theorem. A very nice application of the weak-$\ast$ topology and of Banach--Alaoglu can be found in the proof of Gelfand--Naimark duality (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand_representation). The point is that if $A$ is a commutative unital $C^\ast$-algebra (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C*-algebra), then the set $M(A)$ of characters of $A$ (unital $\ast$-homomorphisms $A \to \mathbb{C}$) is a closed subset of the unit ball of the dual of $A$ as a Banach space, with the weak-$\ast$ topology...

Comment: ...so that by Banach--Alaoglu, $M(A)$ is compact. The upshot then is that $A$ is therefore $\ast$-isomorphic to the commutative unital $C^\ast$-algebra $C(M(A))$ of continuous complex-valued functions on the *compact* Hausdorff space $M(A)$, so that every commutative unital $C^\ast$-algebra, up to $\ast$-isomorphism, is of the form $C(X)$ for a unique (up to homeomorphism) compact Hausdorff space $X$.

Comment: Usually, if you think something your teacher said is "wrong", you will learn a lot by discussing it with her/him.

Comment: @GEdgar yes~~But sometimes it takes some time before the teacher reply me and I feel uncomfortable to leave question unsolved~~ I have just found this site days ago and I really really enjoy discussing with the masters here!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main use of weak* topology is to provide a topolgy on $V^*$ for a normed space(or a TVS) $V$ such that the unit ball in $V^*$ is compact, which is the Banach-Alaoglu Theorem. There are numerous places in analysis where we use this topology, for example from Riesz Representation theorem, for any locally compact Hausdorff space $X$, if $\mathcal{M}(X) $ is the space of complex Radon measures, then the dual $ C_0(X)^* \cong \mathcal{M}(X) $, So from usual sup norm topology of $ C_0(X) $ you can induce the weak* topology on Radon measures, thus you can have convergence, compactness results in measures. If you are familiar with distribution theory, you find that given the inductive limit topology on $ C^\infty_c(\Omega) $, weak* topology is induced on the space of distributions. This is a fundamental requirement in PDEs.